# HTML Form Blur JQuery Function Call That Calls PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, blur

I am a JQuery/JS newb, and am having trouble with a simple .blur() event call.

Basically I have an html form, with inputs that have "id='validate'" that are supposed to call a php script to validate the existence of what is typed in the input element of the form in the database.

Any help will be appreciated!

At the moment I am getting the error: "SyntaxError: missing : after property id @ line 6"[at 'alert("Called!!"),'], but if I comment it out then nothing happens at all.

HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='../js/validate.js'></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<body>
...  
<form method="POST" action="upload.php?t=0" class="formbox" style="float:left;" name='aform'>
    <label>Category: </label><input type="text" id='validate' maxlength="30" name="category"/><br />

    <input style="margin-left:35%;width:130px;" type="submit" value="Submit Article" />                     
</form>
...
</body>
</html>
```

validate.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#validate').blur(function(){
        $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "../php/validate.php",
                data: aform.elements["category"].value,
                success: function(msg){
                    alert("Category exists!");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Error!");
                }

         });
    });
});
```

validate.php:

```
<?php
    include '../php/db.php';
    echo "Called!";

    $cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['category']);

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Category WHERE Name='".$cat."';");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1){
        echo "Category Exists!";
    }else if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
        echo "No Category with that name found!";
    }else{
        echo "Too many Categories found!";
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For future reference, I was having trouble referencing the POST data, I ended up changing "data: aform.elements["category"].value," to 'data:"cat="+document.querySelector('[name = "category"]').value,' in the js file and referencing "$_POST['cat']" in the php file

Comment: The code now works after removing the alert! I was testing it before and didn't have the outside $(document).ready function until after I had the alert, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I noticed, your `alert` function call should not be placed inside the options object of your ajax call - the ajax call is expecting it's options to be defined as `key : value pairs` - if you want to set an alert that the ajax function has been called you could place it inside the `beforeSend` callback - which fires before the XmlHttpRequest is sent. The code would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#validate').blur(function(){
    $.ajax({

            beforeSend: function() { alert("Called!!"); },
            type: "POST",
            url: "../php/validate.php",
            data: aform.elements["category"].value,
            success: function(msg){
                alert("Category exists!");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error!");
            }

     });
});
});
```

Also as a side note, the id property of a html element should be unique to that document, so if you are using id="validate" on multiple form inputs on the page, the page will not be valid html - try changing your selector to a classname instead and call your blur function like so `$('.validate').blur(function() ...`

Also, the success callback only means that the XmlHttpRequest has completed, giving no indication of what data has been returned by the server, so alerting that the category exists because the request has completed could give you a false positive, a better approach would be to use `alert(msg)` inside your success callback.

Here's the link to the query docs on [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which should clear a few things up for you:

Comment: Thank you! It's always nice to have best-practice information handy

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

`alert("Called!!"),`

is misplaced.

Please remove it.

As `$.ajax()` function expects only key values pairs.

And `alert` is function.

You can place it in `success` or `error` function.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot, but I was also wondering why nothing is happening(that's why I put the alert there in the first place, to see if it is called)

Comment: Debug in Mozilla Firebug. Check in the net tab whether Server Request is going.

Answer (score 0):

First issue i see is the alert() call in the object being passed to ajax(), this is invalid and will throw an error